# Can't convert from double to integer due to loss of precision

Tags: r

I am working on the below data frame where i am trying to multiply the variable x1 with 1.1, x2 with 1.2 and x3 with 1.3 , but i get the below error

**Can't convert from double to integer due to loss of precision**

Could you please let me know the reason for this and a solution. If i use the integer values (1, 2, 3) then i dont get that error, but i have to use double values to multiply

```
test <- data.frame(x1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                   x2=c(2,3,4,5,6,7),
                   x3=c(3,4,5,6,7,8))

test2 <- test %>% mutate(across(c(x1,x2,x3),.names='y_{.col}')*across(c(1.1,1.2,1.3)))
```

Comment: If i follow the above logic the above code then the result of x1*1.1 , x2*1.2 and x3*1.3 is not happening , its giving a wrong results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `mapply`.

```
cbind(test, mapply(`*`, test, y))
```

More specific:

```
cbind(test, `colnames<-`(mapply(`*`, test, y), paste0('y', seq_along(y))))
#   x1 x2 x3  y1  y2   y3
# 1  1  2  3 1.1 2.4  3.9
# 2  2  3  4 2.2 3.6  5.2
# 3  3  4  5 3.3 4.8  6.5
# 4  4  5  6 4.4 6.0  7.8
# 5  5  6  7 5.5 7.2  9.1
# 6  6  7  8 6.6 8.4 10.4
```

---

*Data:*

```
test <- structure(list(x1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), x2 = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
7), x3 = c(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

y <- c(1.1, 1.2, 1.3)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get what you want using the base package with the following code

```
# Initial test data.frame
  test <- data.frame(x1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                     x2=c(2,3,4,5,6,7),
                     x3=c(3,4,5,6,7,8))
# Agregate new columns
  test <- cbind(test, y1 = test[,1]*1.1,
                      y2 = test[,2]*1.2,
                      y3 = test[,3]*1.3)
```